# Can not get Razor to work in 4.7

Tags: razor, umbraco

I create a new Razor scripting file. just a test string in there (no actual razor code), then put the macro in a template and it displays:

> Error loading MacroEngine script (file: test.razor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the macro scripts have the extension `.cshtml` (not `.razor`) and are placed in the `/macroScripts` folder.

The macros usually look like this:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@{
    // razor & html
    <div>A simple div</div>
}
```

You may try by simply putting a `@{ ... }` around your test string (as well as renaming the extension to cshtml).

Comment: What exactly is your actual script?